# No SPI response. GoPiGo3 with address 8 not connected

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, raspbian-buster

I am trying to use my GoPiGo3 with my raspberry pi but they don't seem to connect well to each other.

When I try to to update the Firmware of my GoPiGo3, I get this error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~Dexter/GoPiGo3/Firmware $ bash gopigo3_flash_firmware.sh

No SPI response. GoPiGo3 with address 8 not connected.
Firmware upgrade is needed
Attempting to upgrade firmware.
Using interface file 'rpi2.cpg' for RPi version 'RPI3'.
/home/pi/Dexter/GoPiGo3/Firmware
/home/pi/Dexter/GoPiGo3/Firmware/GoPiGo3_Firmware_1.0.0.bin
Updating the GoPiGo3 Firmware with '/home/pi/Dexter/GoPiGo3/Firmware/GoPiGo3_Firmware_1.0.0.bin'
openocd: error while loading shared libraries: libusb-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
   File "build/bdist.linux-aarch64/egg/gopigo3.py", line 244, in __init__
IOError: No SPI response. GoPiGo3 with address 8 not connected.
```

But I do have a green light on my GoPiGo3 led indicating the connection is working (I suppose).

And when I try:

```
sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0
```

I get:

```
libusb-1.0-0 is already latest version (2:1.0.22-2).
```

Does anyone have a solution for me?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so my solution was to comment "dtparam=i2s=on" in the /boot/config.txt file:

```
# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces    
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
dtparam=spi=on
```